# Chrome Cookies API and Manifest 3 - No host permissions for cookies at url

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a cookie using chrome.cookies.set but the documentation seems like hieroglyphics to me. I have "cookies" in "permissions" but I get the error:

No host permissions for cookies at url

I think my stumbling block is specifying the url in 'details'. Although the documentation seems to say 'url' is optional, I get an error saying it is required. The page in question (named config.html) is in my extension root directory and is opened by a button listener in the default_popup html file. Here is my manifest:

```
{
   "manifest_version": 3,

   "name": "Auto_Select",
   "description": "This extension auto selects Mturk HITs",
   "version": "1.0",

   "action": {
       "default_icon": "auto_select.png",
       "type": "module",
       "default_popup": "auto_select.html"
   },
   "permissions": [
       "tabs",
       "cookies",
       "activeTab"
   ],
   "host_permissions": [
       "<all_urls>"
   ]
}
```

Here is the javascript that tries to add the cookie:

```
function create_cookie(obj=null) {
   var json_array=[];
   if (obj==null) {
       json_array=[{requester: false},{title:false},{none:true}];
   }
   else {
       json_array=obj;
   }
   details={
       url: "config.html",
       name: "Auto_Select_0519669",
       value: JSON.stringify(json_array),
       expirationDate: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
   };
   chrome.cookies.set(details);
}

create_cookie();
details={
   url: "config.html",
   name: "Auto_Select_0519669"
}
data=chrome.cookies.get(details);
console.log(data);
```

How do I specify (I've tried several iterations) the the 'url' of a page in the extension root directory? TIA.

Comment: config.html is not a valid URL. Setting cookies for extensions is not supported because there's no server, the extension page is just a local file. What are you trying to achieve? P.S. The url is optional only if another identification is provided e.g. domain.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am trying to set up a configuration page that stores settings for the extension. I thought cookies was the way to go but obviously not. I guess I'll try localStorage instead.

Comment: Note that since localStorage is not available in the background script you may want to use `chrome.storage` instead.